# How to plot rolling mean in ascending order

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have data collected from a machine on a daily basis. The machine runs for 500 cycles every day. The left column shows the time taken by the machine for the 0th, 1st, 2nd and so on cycle:

[image]

I want to plot the daily mean of the data. I am using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))

dotrm = dot.groupby(dot.Date).mean()
dotrm['Rmean'] = dotrm.rolling(1).sum()
plt.plot(dotrm['Rmean'], color='crimson')
```

The output works fine until the month is changed in March. The plot begins from the start. I want it to continue plotting for March after the end of February. The output looks like this:

[image]

Is there any solution to this issue? Thanks

Comment: @BigBen here you go

Comment: I was able to sort the values just by applying sort=False in the groupby: 

dotrm = dot.groupby(dot.Date, sort=False).mean()